# Calculating number of rows when one column variable equals another in R

Tags: r, data-analysis

Would be grateful for help:

I have dichotomised inter-rater variables for analysis

```
df <- data.frame("rater 1"=c(1,1,0,0,1), "rater 2"=c(1,0,0,1,1))
```

I want to know the number of rows where rater 1 = 1 and rater 2 = 1 (a true positive)

and similarly where rater 1 = 0 and rater 2 = 0 (a true negative)

and similarly where rater 1 = 1 and rater 2 = 0 (false positive)
etc

is there an easy way to do this?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(outcome = case_when(rater.1 == 1 & rater.2 == 1 ~ "true positive", 
                             rater.1 == 0 & rater.2 == 0 ~ "true negative", 
                             rater.1 == 1 & rater.2 == 0 ~ "false positive", 
                             rater.1 == 0 & rater.2 == 1 ~ "false negative")
) %>% 
  group_by(outcome) %>% summarise(n = n())
```

Be careful when you name variables with space character

Comment: How do I then count the number of "true positive" as ultimately I need to form a 2x2 contingency table

Comment: I currently get:
```
summary(df$outcome)
```
Length     Class      Mode 
        5 character character

Comment: sorted: 
``` df$outcome <- as.factor(df$outcome)
summary(df$outcome)
```

Comment: I changed the answer to add the count.

Answer (score 2):

You could use base R `table`  which returns the count of unique combinations.

```
table(df)

#----
        rater.2
rater.1  0 1
      0  1 1
      1  1 2
```

Or you could use `dplyr::count`

```
dplyr::count(df, rater.1, rater.2)

#------
  rater.1 rater.2 n
1       0       0 1
2       0       1 1
3       1       0 1
4       1       1 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `aggregate` if you want to have counts in a data frame

```
> aggregate(cnt ~ ., cbind(df, cnt = 1), sum)
  rater.1 rater.2 cnt
1       0       0   1
2       1       0   1
3       0       1   1
4       1       1   2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `rowsum` from `base R`

```
rowsum(rep(1, nrow(df)), group =do.call(paste, df))
```